# How do I fix when GIMP Pencil/Paintbrush tools only draw in a grayscale gradient and are unresponsive to colour changes?

Tags: ubuntu, gimp

So the problem is that the brush tools in GIMP ignore color, and instead always draw in a gradient, going from black to white and vice versa, like so (drawn bottom to top):
[The error in a set of zigzags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liTmC.png)

This has persisted between restarts of my computer, and is limited to the pencil and paintbrush tools. I also think that it continues after uninstalling and reinstalling GIMP. I am using Ubuntu 19.10, and GIMP 2.10.8.

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two causes:

1. Your image is a grayscale mode image (=does not contain color).
2. you have a layer or mode set that makes the image show (=get rendered) in grayscale.

"2" is possible to create in many ways.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think that that's the problem since it only applies to certain brushes, and also happens on otherwise color images - the ink tool works just fine for example.